# NSDictionary element to UITextfield

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, nsdictionary

I have a `NSDictionary` with some parameters I want to display in a `UITextField`. but

```
firstname.text = [userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"];
```

throws an exeption. If I use NSLog on `[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"];` it shows the right value.

This is the thrown exception:

> 2012-07-05 15:55:56.533 Project[13642:f803] -[__NSArrayM
>   _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c4e20 2012-07-05 15:55:56.534 Project[13642:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM
>   _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c4e20'

If I use

```
firstname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
```

it works, but it puts the values in brackets.
What seems to be the problem here? And why doesn't the first attempt work?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that when you change the first attempt, it works? Basically, are you sure the error is on that line?

Comment: it throws the exception on that line when i debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_isNaturallyRTL
```

is an undocumented NSString method. It seems that

```
[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"]
```

is an NSMutableArray (guessed from class name), which you're trying to use as a string. When you use a format string with the %@ format specifier, it calls the `-description` method of the object to be formatted/printed (so does NSLog), and the description of an NSArray is an NSString that looks like

```
[ "description of first element", "description of second element" ]
```

etc., that's why it puts your text in brackets but doesn't crash.

All in all, use

```
[[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"] objectAtIndex:0]
```

instead.

Comment: that was it, I'm sure there is only 1 element in that array, but I forgot to call that element.... well thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
firstname.text = [[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"]stringValue];
```

Does this do any difference?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that `[userdata objectForKey:@"firstname"]` is returning an array that contains just the string you are after. Take a look at where you set the value for "firstname" and change it to be just the string that you are after.

Comment: I get the NSDictionary from a database via Json, and yes it only contains 1 String "firstname"